# Do companion objects remain in memory for app's lifecycle

Tags: android, kotlin

In Kotlin, you can create a singleton using a companion object:

```
class MyClass {
   companion object {
        fun doSomething() {

        }
    }
}
```

According to the Kotlin docs, it states:

> Note that, even though the members of companion objects look like
>   static members in other languages, at runtime those are still instance
>   members of real objects...

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html

Does this mean that after using a function in the companion object, the instance of the class (MyClass) remains in memory for the entire lifecycle of the app? Is there a way in Android Studio to check to see if this is the case?

Comment: Can you provide the link to the doc you reffered?

Comment: Linked added to post.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> ***instance of the class (MyClass) remains in memory for the entire lifecycle of the app***?

### Companion object in JVM

**in kotlin**

```
class MyClass {
   companion object {
        fun doSomething() {

        }
    }
}
```

**MyClass(Kotlin) converted in JVM**

```java
public final class MyClass {
   public static final MyClass.Companion Companion = new MyClass.Companion(null);

   public static final class Companion {
      public final void doSomething() {
      }

      private Companion() {
      }

      public Companion() {
         this();
      }
   }
}
```

As above code, `companion object` is declared as `Companion` class in JVM, and it's created as `static` field inside `MyClass` class. Thus, isn't collected by gc. So, the memory of object(Companion) is remained during the `ProcessLifecycle`. `static final object` isn't released in normal case.

In conclusion, if referred to `MyClass.Companion` instance in application, that **instance will not be garbage collected. (on general Classloaders).**

*If not referred to `MyClass.Companion` instance in application, it may be removed by **code shrinking** feature.

> ***Is there a way in Android Studio to check to see if this is the case?***

You can see through **android studio > profiler > Heap dump.**

### Reference

- https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory-overview
- https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

Comment: Nice answer! But how did you find the "MyClass(Kotlin) converted in JVM" code??

Comment: You can use android studio to convert the kotlin to bytecode and decompile it.

Answer (score 10):

As you seem to know and the above answer also makes clear that companion objects are translated to classes, and the class which declares them holds a static reference to the object of companion class, something as following:

```
public static final MyClass.Companion Companion = new MyClass.Companion(null);
```

Now the question

> Do companion objects remain in memory for app's lifecycle

because the declaring class holds a `static` reference to companion class, the question reduces to the life time of `static` fields in jvm `class` and the answer lies in the [JVM spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se13/jvms13.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A8%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C72%2C590%2Cnull%5D), but the spec is bit dry on the explanation so I am adding some snippets from the book [Inside the Java Virtual Machine](https://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/).

As in your example let say we have a `class` with nothing but single companion object.

**First question is when an object of companion class will be created ?** *or
   when `static` fields are initialized ?*

relevant text from the [book](https://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/lifetype.html). (for context the book is talking about class loading procedure)

> Initialization
>
> The final step required to
>   ready a class or interface for its first active use is initialization,
>   the process of setting class variables to their proper initial values.
>   As used here, a "proper" initial value is the programmerís desired
>   starting value for a class variable. A proper initial value contrasts
>   with the default initial value given to class variables during
>   preparation. As described above, the virtual machine assigns default
>   values based only on each variableís type. Proper initial values, by
>   contrast, are based on some master plan known only to the programmer.
>   In Java code, a proper initial value is specified via a class variable
>   initializer or static initializer.

So we know that once `MyClass` is loaded and initialized, the object of companion class will be created.

**but what would cause JVM to load `MyClass` ?**

> The Java Virtual Machine specification gives implementations
>   flexibility in the timing of class and interface loading and linking,
>   but strictly defines the timing of initialization. All implementations
>   must initialize each class and interface on its first active use. An
>   active use of a class is:
>
> 1. The invocation of a constructor on a new
>      instance of the class
> 2. The creation of an array that has the class as
>      its an element type
> 3. The invocation of a method declared by the class
>      (not inherited from a superclass)
>
> 4 The use or assignment of a field
>   declared by the class (not inherited from a superclass or
>   super interface), except for fields that are both static and final, and
>   are initialized by a compile-time constant expression

So as per 4th point when you do `MyClass.foo()` from kotlin or `MyClass.Companion.foo()` at this point `MyClass` will be loaded and ready. (Probably a lot early)

Please note that at this point no object of `MyClass` exist, that is we haven't used expression `MyClass()`.

**Does this mean `static` fields will remain in memory as long as the application is running ?**

They can be garbage collected if the declaring type gets unloaded, in our case if JVM or ART (on android) unloads the `MyClass` then there is a possibility that companion object will be Garbage collected.

[JVM Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.7) has following to say about class unloading

> An implementation of the Java programming language may unload classes.
>
> A class or interface may be unloaded if and only if its defining class
>   loader may be reclaimed by the garbage collector as discussed in
>   §12.6.
>
> Classes and interfaces loaded by the bootstrap loader may not be
>   unloaded.

In practicality class unloading almost(I said almost) never happens, **so yes companion objects will remain in memory for app's life cycle**.